# Can I use DEFAULT to set a Timestamp in an UPDATE command in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

My hosting provider updated our MySQL yesterday and now significant parts of my website are non-functional. After investigation I have found that any UPDATE commands which specify that a Timestamp should be set to DEFAULT are failing to update the Timestamp. This is a website which has been running perfectly for 2 years. The new MySQL version is 10.2.23-MariaDB-log-cll-lve.

For example, using the following table and populating it with some data:

```
CREATE TABLE `NewTable` ( `NewTableKEY` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , `NewTableTime` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , PRIMARY KEY (`NewTableKEY`));

INSERT INTO `NewTable` (`NewTableKEY`, `NewTableTime`) VALUES (NULL, DEFAULT);
```

I try to update the timestamp using DEFAULT:

```
UPDATE NewTable SET NewTableTime=DEFAULT;
```

In phpMyAdmin, the response I get is:

```
 0 rows affected. (Query took 0.0005 seconds.)
```

I have also tried using NULL instead of default:

```
UPDATE NewTable SET NewTableTime=NULL;
```

Using NULL in this way does update the Timestamp field to the current time. I have found that using DEFAULT in an INSERT command works just fine. I have also found that the "on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" function works as expected.

It was my understanding that using DEFAULT in an UPDATE command was the correct syntax (and it has been working for years). Am I using the wrong syntax? Has this syntax been deprecated? If so, what is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Change your table definition to the following

```
CREATE TABLE `NewTable` ( `NewTableKEY` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
      `NewTableTime` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
      PRIMARY KEY (`NewTableKEY`));
```

This will automatically update the timestamp on the execution of the `UPDATE` query. DEFAULT only caters to insert statement, but if you specify the `ON UPDATE`, MySQL automatically updates the field value (you don't have to code)

Refer to [https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html ] for more details.

Hope this helps

If you want to update as per your conditions either write your own code or USE a trigger, something similar to below,

```
CREATE TRIGGER _triggerName AFTER UPDATE ON _tableName FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    -- Your conditions 
    -- Your queries Based on the conditions 
END;
```

Comment: Thanks, but I do not want the timestamp to update when the table is updated, only when I tell it to.

Comment: In such case EITHER write your own code OR write a `TRIGGER` which can update based on your Conditions; Try using 

    `CREATE TRIGGER _triggerName AFTER UPDATE ON _tableName FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
-- Your conditions 
-- Your queries Based on the conditions

   END;`

Comment: Updated the answer such that the code appears proper for better readability. Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks. I could rewrite it, but what I really want to know is why the functionality that I have been using is no longer working (or rather, what is the correct syntax for this functionality in newer versions of MySQL?). Or has this functionality just been removed?

Comment: I have just tried changing DEFAULT to NULL in all of these commands and that works fine, but I am concerned about forwards compatibility, as it is my understanding that DEFAULT is the correct syntax and NULL is not.

Comment: Always remember, with respect to `TIMESTAMP`, "_An auto-initialized column is set to the current timestamp for inserted rows that specify no value for the column_" refer to the link above in the answer. Thus, for your requirements, your column settings may require change, for ex. you may remove `NOT NULL` and set `DEFAULT NULL` as per your need.